# Second Text component in View line break

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, expo

I have two  components following each other in  component and I wanna so that the first component stretches as long as it can and then ellipsizing, but second component stayed close to first without ellipsizing and then in the right with ellipsized first component.

I've tried everything that I can think of but without success. This correctly works on the web but is not on the iOS and Android

Example:

```js
<View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row', }}>
    <Text numberOfLines={1}>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa.
    </Text>
    <Text>
        1000ms
    </Text>
</View>
```

This is Demo of that problem: https://snack.expo.dev/@volodyaspace/second-component-line-break.

The text components muck more than expected:

[image: the text components much more than expected]

Comment: Please post the html as a text, and not a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `flex: 1` to the text should position it well

https://snack.expo.dev/@dhatguy/ab3739?platform=android

Comment: This works if I need the first <Text /> component to be on the left and the second component is always on the right relative to the container, I need the components to follow each other.